# Python 3.6 Variable Substitution on a Dict Object

Tags: python

I have the following dict object:

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
}
```

I want to define elements of it from variables:

```
# Load environmental variables here
hostname = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_SERVER']
binduser = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER']
bindgroup = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_BIND_GROUP']
dc1 = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DC1']
dc2 = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DC2']
bindpassword = os.environ['AUTH_LDAP_PASSWORD']

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,{bindgroup},dc={dc1),dc={dc2}",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}",
    "is_superuser": "cn=administrators,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}"
}
```

How can I insert the variables into the dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.6+ you have [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": f"cn=active,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}",
    "is_staff": f"cn=staff,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}",
    "is_superuser": f"cn=administrators,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}"
}
```

If you're using python 3.5 or older you can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,{},dc={},dc={}".format(bindgroup, dc1, dc2),
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,{},dc={},dc={}".format(bindgroup, dc1, dc2),
    "is_superuser": "cn=administrators,{},dc={},dc={}".format(bindgroup, dc1, dc2)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is add an `f` in front of the strings you want formatted. Documentation on [f-strings](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/).

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": f"cn=active,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}",
    "is_staff": f"cn=staff,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}",
    "is_superuser": f"cn=administrators,{bindgroup},dc={dc1},dc={dc2}"
}
```

Also, I would use [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.getenv) to avoid KeyError's.